# Class template in ReSharper 9

Tags: c#, resharper, live-templates

I'm trying R#9 EAP now.
I have defined a test class live template.

First parameter `$Some$` is a type reference, which works well.

But there is a problem with second parameter `$Member$`. 
If i do replacement at place #1 in xml doc comment, and member method has some parameter(s), then into test method name includes some garbage. The ACT statement is pretty optional, but I would have the class and method name correctly filled. I think R#8 was not too smart here and added just a member name here. How to accomplish this now? Which parameter macro is suitable for that?

```
///<summary>Tests for <see cref="$Some$"/></summary>
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClassAttribute]
public class $Some$Test
{
    ///<summary>Test for <see cref="$Some$.$Member$"/></summary>
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute]
    public void $Member$Test()
    {
        // ARRANGE
        $END$
        // ACT
        new $Some$().$Member$
        // ASSERT
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you should report this to JetBrains so that they can fix it?

Comment: Good idea. But I'm not sure where to ask and not sure whether JetBrains or I should fix it. Is here a wrong place for such stuff?

Comment: See http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program

Comment: Contact JB ReSharper Support via http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/

Comment: Have already asked in [forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5526685#5526685)